# how to Checking if the value is empty when converting data

Tags: asp.net-core

I check the ExitDate in the condition, but if someone has an empty ExitDate, an error occurs when converting the date. How can I handle this error?

```
public IActionResult paySalery(int id)
{
    var join2Tbl = (from c in _context.Persons
                    join p in _context.Projects on c.projectID equals p.projectID

                    where p.projectID == id

                    select new ProjectViewModel()
                    {

                        projectID = c.projectID,
                        PersonID = c.PersonID,
                        projectName = p.projectName,
                        Family = c.Family,
                        PersonName = c.PersonName,
                        PersonCode = c.PersonCode,
                        PersonAddress = c.PersonAddress,
                        PersonKasreBemeeVaMaliytState = c.PersonKasreBemeeVaMaliytState,

                        **ExitDate = c.ExitDate**
                    }

        ).AsEnumerable();

    var testList = join2Tbl.Where(a => (ConvertDateTime.ConvertShamsiToMiladi(a.ExitDate) >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1))).AsEnumerable();

    return View(testList.ToList());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an error in your first query, try to make ExitDate nullable.

If you have an error in `var testList ...` line, you can deal with it using two ways:

1. Set a default value for ExitDate when you are selecting it like `ExitDate = c.ExitDate == null ? DateTime.MinValue : c.ExitDate`
2. Skip objects with empty ExitDate `.Where(o => o.ExitDate != null)`